# How to save the value_counts in dataframe and pull out the related data from original Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, frequency

I want to find the frequently repeated element in a column and save the results as Dataframe then pull out the related information of those elements from the original Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : np.random.randint(1000, 1005, ( 10)),
                        'B' : pd.Categorical(['company0', 'company1', 'company1', 'company2', 'company5', 'company5', 'company0', 'company5', 'company2', 'company2']),
                        'C' : 'foo',
                        'D' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","train","cup","bib","bib","test",'bib',"cup","cup"]),
                         })


# # generate 'company' DF
company = pd.DataFrame(df.B.value_counts().reset_index())
company.columns = ['B', 'count']
print(brands)

# # merge 'df' & 'company_count'
merged = pd.merge(df, company, on='B')
print(merged)
```

the above code gives me

```
     A         B    C      D    count
0  1003  company0  foo   test      2
1  1002  company0  foo   test      2
2  1004  company1  foo  train      2
3  1004  company1  foo  train      2
4  1001  company2  foo    cup      3
5  1000  company2  foo    cup      3
6  1003  company2  foo    cup      3
7  1000  company5  foo    bib      3
8  1004  company5  foo    bib      3
9  1001  company5  foo    bib      3
```

but what I want is

```
          B  count    D
0  company5      3    bib
1  company2      3    cup
2  company1      2    train
3  company0      2    test
```

How can I get the result that I want?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look, one `B` has one unique `D`. If so, you can do:

```
(df.groupby(['B','D'], observed=True).size()
   .reset_index(name='count')
)
```

Output:

```
          B      D  count
0  company0   test      2
1  company1  train      2
2  company2    cup      3
3  company5    bib      3
```